# android 6+ audio streaming broken lamemp3

Tags: java, android, mp3, android-mediaplayer, lame

I have an android application source code that uses lamemp3 to record and stream audio. as of android 6+ the audio stream is clipping and seems to be over driving the mic and the sound is distorted.

for android 5 and below the same code works fine..

I dont even know where to start looking for the problem, and was hoping someone could suggest any audio changes that were made in android 6+ that would cause these results?